# How to implement the callback URL for 'Upwork' REST API?

Tags: python, php, rest, upwork-api

To be able to run this code (search jobs from upwork.com):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import upwork
from upwork.routers.jobs import search

# https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#authentication_authorization-request
# https://www.upwork.com/developer/keys/apply
config = upwork.Config(
        {
            "client_id": <my_client_id>,
            "client_secret": <my_client_secret>,
            "redirect_uri": <my_redirect_uri>
        }
    )

client = upwork.Client(config)

try:
    config.token
except AttributeError:
    authorization_url, state = client.get_authorization_url()
    # cover "state" flow if needed
    authz_code = input(
        "Please enter the full callback URL you get "
        "following this link:\n{0}\n\n> ".format(authorization_url)
    )

    print("Retrieving access and refresh tokens.... ")
    token = client.get_access_token(authz_code)

params = {'q': 'php', 'title': 'Web developer'}
search.Api(client).find(params)
```

I need to define a *callback URL*.

How do I implement it?

Anyone have a [php](/questions/tagged/php) or [python](/questions/tagged/python) script to do it?

How you fetch (client side) the returned values from the API from your callback (server side)? <s>Or you need a web service on your localhost?</s> I can't host a web service on my localhost, because **I don't have the hand on the network to forward to my private IP**

**Looks like it's easier to scrape the site than using API :/** What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this with change your `redirect_uri` configuration with your actual callback URL. I'm not so familiar with `php` but how about implement the callback URL with flask?

the minimalistic setup should be like

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import upwork

app = Flask(__name__)

client_id = "<my_client_id>"
client_secret = "<my_client_secret>"
redirect_uri = "<my_redirect_uri>"

config = upwork.Config(
    {
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri
    }
)

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    # Get the authorization code from the request
    auth_code = request.args.get('code')
    client = upwork.Client(config)
    token = client.get_access_token(auth_code)
    return f"Access token: {token.access_token}\nRefresh token: {token.refresh_token}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

you can test it in your local machine by running the flask server, and after you got authorized, the Upwork client will be called your `redirect_uri` (in here it could be navigated to the `http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback` url) and the `callback()` method will be called.

If you wanted to get the returned response from your callback URL, you can fetch it with `requests` library like

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback")
if response.status_code != 200:
   response.raise_for_status()
else:
   access_token, refresh_token = response.text.strip().split('\n')
   print(f"Access token: {access_token}\n Refresh token: {refresh_token}"
```

please bear in mind, that you will need to modify this code based on your case and the structure of your own server-side endpoint and also the way you setup the Upwork configuration.

Comment: I wrote that I can't test on localhost. I have a datacenter server